Why after disabling adblockers in Chrome no browsers can access Google Analytics?
I had two ad blockers in chrome which I have now disabled and removed. However, they have left behind some of their instructions.
I cannot click on any google ad links from any browser which I now need to do as I am running ads.
I cannot use Google analytics with:

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/academy/

But I can go here:

https://tagmanager.google.com/#/home

But if I select an analytics account like:

https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#embed/report-home/a116505845w172941436p172396281/

I get:

This site can’t be reached. Check if there is a typo in analytics.google.com If spelling is correct, try running windows network Diagnostics. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Do I need to do a registry clean? The adblockers have clearly messed something up.
I tried CCleaner but no joy.

You disabled the extension or uninstalled the extensions?

I said on all browsers

Uninstalled all extensions

Perhaps Google has black-listed your machine by IP address. Try using a different IP, e.g., from a public provider, or via VPN.

Which adblockers did you have installed? Were you able to click ads or access Google Analytics while these adblockers were installed (You slightly imply this, but you don't actually state whether or not this was the case).

I found the issue. It was external. I followed the new windows AI suggestions:
Switching to Google DNS can help improve your internet speed and reliability. Here’s a step-by-step guide to change your DNS settings on a Windows computer:
Open Network Settings:

Right-click on the network icon in your system tray (bottom-right corner of your screen).
Select “Open Network & Internet settings”.

Change Adapter Options:

In the settings window, click on “Change adapter options”.

Select Your Network:

Right-click on your active network connection (Wi-Fi or Ethernet) and select “Properties”.

Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4):

In the properties window, find and select “Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)”.

Click on “Properties”.


Enter DNS Server Addresses:

Select “Use the following DNS server addresses”.
Enter 8.8.8.8 for the Preferred DNS server.
Enter 8.8.4.4 for the Alternate DNS server.

Save Settings:

Click “OK” to save your changes.
Close all windows.
Google analytics and ads now appear.

